# Add per-site Meta questions and answers to network profile Top Questions and Top Answers lists

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, network-profile

When I look at my own [Stack Exchange profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/372965/simon-sheehan), I can see all my top questions and answers by their score on there. Even MSO is there. But some of my best posts are on [Meta Super User](http://meta.superuser.com/users/80670/simon-sheehan). Looking at others, it seems all per-site Meta's are not included.

Why are they excluded from this? And if there isn't a reason why, can we have them added? Some of the best answers and questions users post are on their own sites meta, and they need some time to shine.

Comment: My guess is it's because child meta accounts aren't truly separate.

Comment: @AdamLear what do you mean by that?

Comment: You don't really have a dedicated account on a child meta like you would on any main site. It's linked to the main site account. I'm hazy on the details and implementation, but my theory is that it may be the cause for those accounts not being shown on the Accounts tab and questions & answers made on those meta sites not showing up in the profile as well.

Comment: @AdamLear makes sense to me, good point!

Comment: @Adam this might be a valid reason to decline the request, no?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** Per-site-metas may  be hidden because, by design, actions on them aren't meant to affect standing in the larger SE community.

[As mentioned by Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125675/add-per-site-meta-questions-and-answers-to-network-profile-top-questions-and-top#comment339583_125675), with the exception of [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com), none of the meta sites have their own dedicated accounts. Instead, child meta sites are linked to the main site account.

As per their design, actions on per-site-metas are isolated from the larger SE communities. Reputation is carried over from the main SE account, and posts on the child meta have no effect on reputation.

Even with this explanation, **I agree that per-site-meta questions and answers should be displayed on a user's network profile.** If we can include questions from Meta SE, I see little reason not to include posts from the other meta sites as well.