# What happened with Community♦'s network profile

Tags: bug, community-user, network-profile

1. [Top questions gone](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=top) (used to show two posts from MSE)
2. [No accounts shown except Area 51](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=accounts) (there used to be a list of the accounts)
3. <s>[Activity gone](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity) (it was there)</s> seems to be fixed

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: literally sitebreaking

Comment: #1 is by design: the only upvoted questions of Mr. Community are on child meta sites and child meta posts do not appear in Top Questions or Top Answers in the network profile. There is [pending request to change it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125675/add-per-site-meta-questions-and-answers-to-network-profile-top-questions-and-top).